# workflow between site collection?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

When users Remove list item, it will archive the list item to another site collection. Does it work through workflow?

Note:

Users will no Delete privilege---> will be able to remove outdated or unnecessary docs. from the list until reviewed by a supervisor. . If the supervisor says delete , then will be deleted, But if supervisor decided to keep the docs, it will back to the previous list in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I am not sure why would you do this?  You have a recycle bin which covers up to 90 days and second recycle bin for another 90 days.  If you need to archive the content don't allow users to delete and move content after certain conditions are met.

Comment: Users will no Delete privilege---> will be able to remove outdated or unnecessary docs. from the list. until reviewed by a supervisor. . If the supervisor says delete , then will be deleted, But if supervisor decided to keep the docs, it will back to the previous list.

Comment: This is completely different than what your original question was.  You will need to create a workflow and set the status to delete/no delete etc. and based on the status move the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is when an item has been deleted there is no way trigger a workflow. So you can`t achieve using Workflow.

But you can consider the Event Reciever "An Item is being deleted" which will give you the ability to get the item information and do the subsequent operations.

**Copy Item to Different Site Collection When you set a flag (Active) to No**

You can add the activies in the order shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

1. Build request Headers.

[image]

2. Get the "Form Digest Value" using api call
   `site url/_api/ContextInfo`

[image]

3. Read digest value from the response dictionary
   `d/GetContextWebInformation/FormDigestValue`
4. Build dictionary for `__metadata`

[image]

5. Build dictionary for listitem.

[image]

6. Build dictionary for post request headers

[image]

7. Add HTTP Web Call and set properties.

[image]

It creates item in your list in site collection.

Comment: Users will no Delete privilege---> will be able to remove outdated or unnecessary docs. from the list. until reviewed by a supervisor. . If the supervisor says delete , then will be deleted, But if supervisor decided to keep the docs, it will back to the previous list.

Comment: You mean remove is setting a flag (like Active) in the list item?

Comment: yes setting a flag

Comment: You can create an item in different site collection using workflow when you set a flag.

Comment: Thanks Venkat for prompt respond . This project is for SharePoint 2010. Do you have any idea. Tnx again